# Create design chat with picture like whatsapp in IOS xamarin

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin

How to create design chatting like whatsapp (ios xamarin).
Just like in the picture below:

[image]

My code:

```
ContentView.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("H:|[bubble]",
            0,"bubble", BubbleImageView));
            ContentView.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("V:|-2-[bubble]-2-|",0,"bubble", BubbleImageView
            ));
            BubbleImageView.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("H:[bubble(>=48)]",0,"bubble", BubbleImageView));

//setting layout for Image Picture

var vSpaceTopAttch = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(ImgPicture, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, BubbleImageView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 10);
                ContentView.AddConstraint(vSpaceTopAttch);

//setting layout for Message Label

var vSpaceTop = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(MessageLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, BubbleImageView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 10);
                ContentView.AddConstraint(vSpaceTop);

var vSpaceBottom = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(MessageLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, BubbleImageView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, -10);
            ContentView.AddConstraint(vSpaceBottom);

var msgLeading = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(MessageLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, BubbleImageView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1, 16);
            ContentView.AddConstraint(msgLeading);

var msgCenter = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(MessageLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, BubbleImageView, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 3);
            ContentView.AddConstraint(msgCenter);
```

Result from this code:

[image]

Position image are behind BubbleImageView. 
How to design the layout like whatsapp in ios xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bringing the subview with the image to the front with:

```
ContentView.BringSubviewToFront(yourImageSubView);
```

?